# Node.js file upload capabilities: Large Video Files Uploading with support for interruption

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to upload large movie file (around 5GB) and at some point interrupt the upload process, log out and come back to the website to resume de upload after 2/3 hours?

Of course, resume should be made from the same computer and referencing the same file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's doable using socket.io, and the HTML5 filereader API. With the filereader API you can slice and dice your video file in smaller chunks and then send those through web sockets to Node.js. Because this chunks are well defined and enumerable, you can resume the upload whenever you want as long as the server keeps track of the current chunks downloaded. You may find [this interesting tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-resumable-video-uploade-in-node-js/) very similar to what your asking for.

Comment: I hate to comment on the old post but can this be done using ftp?

Comment: @powerfade917, unlikely. This answer was describing sending via HTTP WebSocket. I'm not sure Javascript can send any packets to FTP, and nodejs isn't built to listen for ftp sessions/packets.