# Filereader and Socket.io uploader: subsequent uploads include previous uploads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, filereader

I'm trying to implement a file uploader in html5/js and node that uploads large files in chunks. It works great for a single upload. But when I try and upload again on the same page, it goes into an infinite loop where it looks like it's trying to reupload the previous upload and the new file at once.

Client.js

```
$('input').change(function() {
  var file = this.files[0]
  var fileSize = file.size
  var fileName = file.name
  // file size gate:
  var fileSizeLimit = 15000000 // ~15mb
  if (fileSize <= fileSizeLimit) {
    // get preview blob
    var windowURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL
    var blobURL = windowURL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])
    // render preview image
    // render status progress
    // set progress to 0

    // read the file to server:
    var reader = new FileReader()
    console.log('new filereader init')
    socket.emit('startSend', fileName, fileSize, entryID)
    console.log('startSend emitted now for ' + fileName) 

    reader.onload = function(event) {
      var data = event.target.result
      console.log('reader onload for ' + fileName)
      socket.emit('sendPiece', data, fileName, fileSize, entryID)
    }

    socket.on('morePlease', function (place, entryID, percent){
      progressUpdate(percent)
      var chunkSize = 262144
      var startPlace = place * chunkSize // The newBlock's Starting Position
      var newBlock = file.slice(startPlace, startPlace + Math.min(chunkSize, (fileSize-startPlace)))
      reader.readAsBinaryString(newBlock) // triggers reader onload
    })

    function progressUpdate(percent){
      console.log('current percent is: ' + percent + '%')
      $('.sendfile .progress').val(percent).text(percent + '%')
    }

    socket.on('sendSuccessful', function(entryID){
      console.log('sendSuccessful triggered for ' + entryID + '. File should be in temp folder.')
      $('.status .sendfile').addClass('hidden')
      $('.status .savetext').removeClass('hidden')
      $('.status .saved').removeClass('hidden')
      $('.sendfile .progress').val(0).text('0%')
    })

  } else { 
    // file size is too big
  }

}) // close input onchange event
```

Server.js

```
  // start file upload
  var chunkSize = 262144

  socket.on('startSend', function(fileName, fileSize, entryID) {
    var files = {}
    console.log('startSend hit for ' + fileName)
    files[fileName] = { // create new entry in files {}
      fileSize : fileSize,
      data : '',
      downloaded : 0
    }
    var fileWriting = files[fileName]
    var tempPath = 'temp/' +  entryID + '-' + fileName
    var place = 0 // stores where in the file we are up to
    console.log('place: in startSend, the place for ' + fileName + ' is ' + place) //

    try{
      var stat = fs.statSync(tempPath)
      if(stat.isFile())
      {
        fileWriting['downloaded'] = stat.size
        place = stat.size / chunkSize; // we're passing data in 1/4 mb increments
        console.log('downloaded: ' + stat.size)
      }
    }
    catch(er){} // it's a new file
    fs.open(tempPath, "a", 0755, function(err, fd){
      if(err)
      {
        console.log(err)
      }
      else // requesting
      {
        fileWriting['handler'] = fd //We store the file handler so we can write to it later
        var percent = 0
        socket.emit('morePlease', place, entryID, percent) // requesting more file pieces
      }
    })

    // processing the file pieces from client
    socket.on('sendPiece', function(data, fileName, fileSize, entryID) {
      console.log('sendPiece hit for ' + entryID + ' ' + fileName) 
      fileWriting['downloaded'] += data.length
      fileWriting['data'] += data
      if(fileWriting['downloaded'] == fileWriting['fileSize']) { // If File is Fully Uploaded
        fs.write(fileWriting['handler'], fileWriting['data'], null, 'Binary', function(err, Writen){
          console.log('file ' + entryID + 'has been written to temp folder: ' + fileName)
          socket.emit('sendSuccessful', entryID)
        })
      }
      else if(fileWriting['data'].length > 10485760){ //If the Data Buffer reaches 10MB
        fs.write(fileWriting['handler'], fileWriting['data'], null, 'Binary', function(err, Writen){
          fileWriting['data'] = ""; //Reset The Buffer
          var place = fileWriting['downloaded'] / chunkSize
          var percent = (fileWriting['downloaded'] / fileWriting['fileSize']) * 100
          socket.emit('MorePlease', place, entryID, percent) // requesting more file pieces
        })
      }
      else { // need more file pieces
        var place = fileWriting['downloaded'] / chunkSize
        console.log('MorePlease: ' + fileName + ' pieces needed at place ' + place + ' and percent ' + percent)
        var percent = (fileWriting['downloaded'] / fileWriting['fileSize']) * 100
          socket.emit('morePlease', place, entryID, percent) // requesting more file pieces
      }
    })
  }) // close startSend
```

---

server log: Here's the node log based on the console.logs scattered throughout:

uploading the first file goes fine:

```
startSend hit for file1.jpeg
place: in startSend, the place for file1.jpeg is 0
sendPiece hit for 52a530f8649b5db8b2000001 file1.jpeg
file 52a530f8649b5db8b2000001has been written to temp folder: file1.jpeg
```

and for the subsequent file:

```
startSend hit for file2.JPG
place: in startSend, the place for file2.JPG is 0
sendPiece hit for 52a530f8649b5db8b2000001 file1.jpeg
MorePlease: file1.jpeg pieces needed at place 1.9332275390625 and percent undefined
sendPiece hit for 52a530f8649b5db8b2000001 file1.jpeg
MorePlease: file1.jpeg pieces needed at place 0.96661376953125 and percent undefined
sendPiece hit for 52a530f8649b5db8b2000001 file2.JPG
MorePlease: file2.JPG pieces needed at place 2.6120567321777344 and percent undefined
```

... infinite loop.

---

webinspector messages:

```
reader onload for file1.jpeg (client.js, line 260)
reader onload for file2.JPG (client.js, line 260)
current percent is: 270.227552566774% (client.js, line 273, x2)
current percent is: 242.3942545981759% (client.js, line 273)
InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
```

... infinite loop

---

I've been racking my brain on this for hours , trying to step through the code on my own. I'm not a developer by trade so any help would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never use Socket for file uploading with Node.js. Basically, http does an excellent job. This is example code:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer();
server.listen(8080);
console.log('Start is started on port 8080');

server.on('request', function(req, res) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream('sample.jpg');
    var fileSize = req.headers['content-length'];
    var uploadedSize = 0;

    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        uploadedSize += chunk.length;
        var buffer = file.write(chunk);
        if(buffer == false)
            req.pause();
    });

    file.on('drain', function() {
        req.resume();
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
        res.write('File uploading is completed!!');
        res.end();
    });
});
```

If you want to notify the client about progress uploading, you can add some logic in the `data` event.

By the way, I've found that someone already asked the same question and get the answer. The answer posted a link to a tutorial. I've checked and think that it is a solution that you are looking for. Check this [Node.js file upload capabilities: Large Video Files Uploading with support for interruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272198/node-js-file-upload-capabilities-large-video-files-uploading-with-support-for-i)!

Comment: The reason I went with socket, is because I didn't want to do a page refresh on a form submit on the client side. Doesn't the node server.on request type model only work on new html page requests?

Comment: The example that I posted is for server side. Even you use Socket or http for connectivity, you still need a page (or native app) on the client side to submit file to the server. If you want your client to get notification, it has to implement the event (such as "sendSuccessful" event) to receive and process information from the server.

Comment: In the case of client side, with an input onchange event or something like that , how would I pass the event to the server without having to trigger a page refresh on the client (for the http server to register the 'request')? Maybe an example of the clientside of this would make it more clear for me. Thanks again.

Comment: re: the link to nettuts : it's actually what my code was roughly based of off . But I'll double check it too. If I can get uploading with page reloads with your http method, I'd really rather do that.

Comment: yup, ended up switching to an http + node busboy solution. Socket.io is fantastic but not worth the pain for files. Thanks!